# Opening mulitple taps with js in a new window

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of links I need to open at once in a new window. I am aware that you can open links in a new window (without the toolbar) one by one, but I need a fully functional browser window with a toolbar and all links open.

Not like this:

[image: asdf]

But more like this:

[image]
(It's for a chrome extension if that makes a difference.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible. This is most likely not possible for spam prevention.